# Select all rows of one table for each rows of other

Tags: mysql

I have following tables

```
users (id, name)
(1,"Vladimir"), (2,"Svatos")

prices (id, price)
(1,"M"), (2,"T")

userprice (uid, pid, val)
(1,2,1.01), (1,1,1.0)
```

I need make query that return all prices for each user, if user do not have same price column "val" will be "null"

for example

```
name       price uid pid  val   
Vladimir   M       1   1    1    
Vladimir   T       1   2    1.05    
Svatos     M       2   1  NULL    
Svatos     T       2   2  NULL
```

Thanks!

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

solution

SELECT
  u.name,  p.price, u.id, p.id, u1.val
FROM users u
  INNER JOIN prices p
    ON TRUE
  LEFT  JOIN userprice u1
    ON ( p.id = u1.pid AND u.id=u1.uid )   ORDER BY u.name